# swf will not work on server. Runs fine locally

Tags: spring-webflow

I have a banner (XML_Banner.swf) that is supposed to load and rotate images from an XML file (banners.xml). When I preview my the site locally, I get no problems. However, once on the Linux web server the movie seems to load but displays no pictures. Just a black box. If I navigate to the banner it also loads with no problem.

http://www.aaronletourneau.ca/ecometrix/Site/Refresh/banner/XML_Banner.swf

It is probably a very simple fix that I keep overlooking. Here are some details:

- The banner files are located in a folder entitled "banner" inside the root folder for the site.
- I have placed the files XML_Banner.swf, XML_Banner.html, and banners.xml inside the folder "banner".
- Images for the banner are located in a folder "img" inside of "banner".
- The file (AC_RunActiveContent.js) is located inside a folder named "Scripts" inside the banner folder.

Referencing the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/AC_RunActiveContent.js"></script>
```

Embedding code:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="878" HEIGHT="220" id="XML_Banner" ALIGN="">
```

URL:
http://www.aaronletourneau.ca/ecometrix/Site/Refresh/index.html

***EDIT***
Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rotator isRandom="false">
  <bannerTime>5</bannerTime>
  <numberOfBanners>7</numberOfBanners>
  <banners showHeader="true">
    <banner>
      <name>Arrival of Spring.</name>
      <body></body>
      <imagePath>img/01.jpg</imagePath>
      <link>gallery.html</link>
    </banner>
    <banner>
      <name>Fishing in Peru.</name>
      <body></body>
      <imagePath>img/02.jpg</imagePath>
      <link>gallery.html</link>
    </banner>
    <banner>
      <name>Peruvian Cattle.</name>
      <body></body>
      <imagePath>img/03.jpg</imagePath>
      <link>gallery.html</link>
    </banner>
    <banner>
      <name>Shoreline of Port Hawksbury, NS.</name>
      <body></body>
      <imagePath>img/04.jpg</imagePath>
      <link>gallery.html</link>
    </banner>
    <banner>
      <name>Lilies afloat.</name>
      <body></body>
      <imagePath>img/05.jpg</imagePath>
      <link>gallery.html</link>
    </banner>
    <banner>
      <name>Logging road.</name>
      <body></body>
      <imagePath>img/06.jpg</imagePath>
      <link>gallery.html</link>
    </banner>
    <banner>
      <name>Small rapids.</name>
      <body></body>
      <imagePath>img/07.jpg</imagePath>
      <link>gallery.html</link>
    </banner>
  </banners>
</rotator>
```

***EDIT*** Here is my AS:

```
    //Load from XML File
    stop();
    //Banner 
    var banners:Array = new Array();
    //Image Path
    var imagePaths:Array = new Array();
    //Link URL
    var links:Array = new Array();
    //Body Text
    var bodyTexts:Array = new Array();
    //
    var imageTime:Number;
    //
    var numberOfBanners:Number;
    //
    var isRandom:String;
    //
    var showHeader:String;
    //
    var bannersXML:XML = new XML();
    bannersXML.ignoreWhite = true;
    bannersXML.load("banner/banners.xml");
    bannersXML.onLoad = function(success) {
        if (success) {
            trace("XML LOADED");
            imageTime = parseInt(this.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild)*1000;
            numberOfBanners = parseInt(this.firstChild.childNodes[1].firstChild);
            isRandom = this.firstChild.attributes["isRandom"];
            showHeader = this.firstChild.childNodes[2].attributes["showHeader"];

            var bannerSequence:Array = new Array();
            if (isRandom == "true") {
                //Make a random sequence
                while (bannerSequence.length<numberOfBanners) {
                    newRandomNumber = random(numberOfBanners);
                    //Make sure that the random one chosen is not already chosen
                    for (var i = 0; i<=bannerSequence.length; i++) {
                        if (newRandomNumber != bannerSequence[i]) {
                            alreadyThere = false;
                        } else {
                            alreadyThere = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //Add only random values that aren't in the array
                    if (!alreadyThere) {
                        bannerSequence.push(newRandomNumber);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i<numberOfBanners; i++) {
                    bannerSequence.push(i);
                }
            }
        }

        //Read XML in the Random Order Chosen
        for (var i = 0; i<numberOfBanners; i++) {
            banners.push(this.firstChild.childNodes[2].childNodes[bannerSequence[i]].firstChild.firstChild.toString());
            bodyTexts.push(this.firstChild.childNodes[2].childNodes[bannerSequence[i]].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);
            imagePaths.push(this.firstChild.childNodes[2].childNodes[bannerSequence[i]].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue);
            links.push(this.firstChild.childNodes[2].childNodes[bannerSequence[i]].childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue);
        }
        play();
    };
    //Start the image counter at 0
    var imageCounter = 0;

stop();
//Check to see if the banner should be reset
if (imageCounter>=banners.length) {
    imageCounter = 0;
}
//Load banner image  
var imageLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
imageLoader.loadClip("banner/img/"+imagePaths[imageCounter],bannerContainer_mc);
var loadingListener:Object = new Object();
loadingListener.onLoadComplete = function() {
    play();
    //Display Header
    if (showHeader == "true") {
        imageText_mc.headerTxt.text = banners[imageCounter].toString();
    } else {
        imageText_mc.headerTxt.text = "";
        imageText_mc._alpha = 0;
    }
    //Button and Link Handling
    if (links[imageCounter] != null) {
        trace("LINK : "+links[imageCounter]);
        bannerContainer_mc.onRelease = function() {
            getURL(links[imageCounter], "_self");
        };
    } else {
        delete bannerContainer_mc.onRelease;
    }
};
imageLoader.addListener(loadingListener);
```

Is there something incorrect or am I missing anything? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you the paths to the image properly set up for the server environment?

Comment: If the SWF loads fine directly then I would check the JS console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you have wrong urls. The swf searches for your images at

```
http://www.aaronletourneau.ca/ecometrix/Site/Refresh/img/01.jpg
```

but they are located in

```
http://www.aaronletourneau.ca/ecometrix/Site/Refresh/banner/img/01.jpg
```

You can add this relative path in your xml `banner/img/01.jpg` as source or have a `flashVar` with that relative path. You have to modify your AS code to use this relative path, if given.

The swf takes relative url's from the base url of the HTML it is included, not where the swf resides.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Much appreciated. 
Perhaps its the lack of sleep but I am confused by this:
_You can add this relative path in your xml banner/img/01.jpg as source or have a flashVar with that relative path. You have to modify your AS code to use this relative path, if given._

Comment: You can have `flashVar`s defined in your HTML embedding code. This flashVars are available in flash via `contentLoaderInfo`. You can retrieve this value in flash and combine it with your image name from the xml to have the correct relative url for your image. You could also have the complete relative path in your XML, but then, it will not work locally, where the swf and the images are in the same directory with the embedding HTML.

Comment: You could also move your images to `http://www.aaronletourneau.ca/ecometrix/Site/Refresh` for ease.

Comment: DanielB... Thank you for your assistance. It is now solved. 
I am new to this site, is there a thank you button?

Comment: Yes, click on the grey accept button beside my answer. Have a look at [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).